# Making the SocketHandler to log in a file in python

Tags: python, logging

I was looking at the python [`SocketHandler` example](http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/logging-cookbook.html) for how to Sending and receiving logging events across a network. All I want is to make the logger log to a file and not use `StreamHandler`. After looking at the code I can't find where I need to make the changes to log to a file. Can someone please tell me how i can achieve that?
If you find this trivial, I do apologize.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searching i have found an example on the internet that is close to what I was looking. You can find the example here : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577025-loggingwebmonitor-a-central-logging-server-and-mon/.

Sorry again for all the trouble.